# C include style and CLion auto import

Tags: c, clion

I am in a battle about what c include style to use. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-include-and-include-in-c-c-with-examples/) would suggest that the `#include <foo.h>` style be used for system headers and not for anything that you write, and that the `#include "bar.h"` style be used for any user written headers. However, the CLion auto importer for c contradicts this.

Cmake targeting both dirs as include directories to the project but from foo.c the auto importer wants to add <bar.h> despite it being user defined.

[image]
[image]

There's a bit of a war as to what is the correct way to include. my understanding is `<>` looks top down for the header, and `""` looks local and then top down for the header. So the optimisation clion uses is correct in look here if it is here, or look top down if not here?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `<foo.h>` should only be used for system includes. I don't know why CLion doesn't understand this.

Comment: @Barmar, how far out is local? is it exclusively this dir or does it iterate outwards? Ie. will `#include "bar.h"` look at `../../foo/inc/bar.h` or does it look in `./` and then go to the top level and work down?

Comment: Just this directory. You can use relative pathnames like `"../foo.h"` to go to the parent directory, or `"subdir/foo.h"` to go into a subdirectory.

Comment: @Barmar, so if that's the case. Then if you have `/include/lib/foo.h`, `/src/bar/bar.h`, and `/drc/bar/bar.c`; then it os more efficient to do `#include "bar.h"` from `bar.c` but also more efficient to do `#include <foo/foo.h>` from `bar.c` given that it is not in this directory? So it would be correct to use `""` in local context and `<>` in any context not in this dir, right?

Comment: Efficiency isn't the issue. `<>` is for system-provided headers, `""` is for application-provided headers.

Comment: @Barmar ok, fair enough. Do you know why clion disagrees? Annoying ahving auto include do one thing and people arguing for the other in pulls, hence why I am here

Comment: Since CLion is paid software, did you ask JetBrains? And doesn't CLion allow to adjust the preferred way? What good is an IDE if it stands in the way?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a matter of coding style. The convention and purpose of the two different styles is that `#include <header.h>` is for standard/system libraries or other libraries provided by the compiler, and `#include "header.h"` is for everything else, including your own code and any 3rd party libs you are using.

*However*, the C standard explicitly says that when using `#include "header.h"`, the compiler will first look in the local project/user directories and if it can't find the header there, it will then go look in the system libraries, just as if you had typed `#include <header.h>`. Meaning `#include "header.h"` will always work no matter what header you include. Though using that form to include standard/system headers is bad practice, since doing so is unconventional.

If some IDE tries to do the other way around though, `#include <header.h>` for user headers, then that IDE is simply confused and behaving incorrectly.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is what they say CLion is doing.